# Which symbols should be used as placeholders for letters and numerical digits?

Tags: best-practices, mathematics

I need to generally describe the syntax of random alphanumeric sequences, say `ACW3920` or `39B0Q8`, and discuss certain cases, e. g. the first two digits being letters, or the sequence ending with `BA`, `87` or similar. Using `X` as a placeholder character for letters and `N` as a placeholder character for numbers would lead to confusion because some of the discussed cases handle sequences beginning with `X` or `N`: `NXNNNN`, the categorization of the samples `NX9837`, `NX9877`, `NX123X` (all beginning with `NX`), does neither communicate the sub-sequence they all have in common, nor does it take into account digits that can be a letter *or* a number.

Ideally, I would use placeholder symbols that uniquely identify a letter digit, a numeric digit or an ambivalent digit. Are there any already used symbols for such a problem (like `¤` for unspecified currency), that don't look too off between normal letters? Symbols like `\CIRCLE` and its derivates affect the type color too much, and `...` doesn't convey the number of digits.

Comment: choice of notation is off topic here, once you have have chosen the notation, asking how to set it in tex would be on topic.  However why not  use regex or similar notation so `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z0-9]*` for a sequence starting with two letters?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Due to space limitations, the notation can't exceed the samples in length, requiring single characters as placeholders for each digit. However, I was hoping for some advice from a typographical perspective on how one might approach this challenge, and if there are any non-alphanumeric, single-character regular expressions for numbers and/or letters.

Also, is there a more fitting Stack Exchange for such questions? Seems off topic for Mathematics Stack Exchange too.

Comment: (what is the type color?) What about a reverse 2 or reverse L etc.?

Comment: @user202729 I was referring to something known as "Grauwert" in German, it describes how dense or heavy the text appears on the page. A good Grauwert can improve the readability of your document. LaTeX usually helps you with that by default, and can be further improved using the ````microtype```` package.

Comment: @user202729 I like your mirroring approach! Any idea on a glyph that expresses ambivalence to both numbers and letters?

Comment: If the codes are uppercase, what about using lowercase `n` and `x` ? Or even math-mode ones?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer from the TeX point of view. My idea is to set the strings in monospaced font (maybe choose a different one from the default) but the “variable” ones are a boxed D or a boxed L for “digit“ and “letter”. Maybe you can add another symbol for a character that's either a digit or a letter.

The main thing in this code is that it's very customizable: variables are denoted by `?` and `!` (you might choose `d` and `l` if lowercase letters are not used in the strings), the conversion to the boxed characters happens by examining each character in the input and check whether it represents a “variable” (placeholder).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\rstring}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \normalfont\ttfamily
  \mulmet_rstring:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mulmet_rstring:n
 {
  \hspace{0.05em}
  \str_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \str_case:nnF { ##1 }
     {
      {?}{\mulmet_rstring_placeholder:n { D }}
      {!}{\mulmet_rstring_placeholder:n { L }}
     }
     { ##1 }
    \hspace{0.05em}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mulmet_rstring_placeholder:n
 {
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxrule { 0.3pt }
  \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep { 0pt }
  \framebox[0.5em]
   {
    \hspace{-0.3pt}
    \vphantom{A}
    \normalfont\tiny\raisebox{0.4\height}{#1}
    \hspace{-0.3pt}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

We have the full string \rstring{ACW3920} but also
an incomplete one \rstring{AC????} and one with
\rstring{!!????} two letters and four digits.

\noindent one with \rstring{ABCDEF}

\end{document}
```

In the last row I show that strings occupy the same space whether they're full or contain placeholders.

[image]

If you add `\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}` you get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try `\textvisiblespace` if I don't mistake your intention.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

ACW3920\qquad A\textvisiblespace W39\textvisiblespace 0

NX9837\qquad \textvisiblespace X9\textvisiblespace 3\textvisiblespace

\end{document}
```

[image]